# What is the workflow for implementing ERTS NIFs in Zig?

Tags: erlang, zig

What is the workflow for implementing [ERTS NIFs](https://erldocs.com/18.0/erts/erl_nif.html) in Zig?

Is there something comparable to [Rustler](https://github.com/rusterlium/rustler) for NIFs authored in Rust?

Comment: Zigler? https://hexdocs.pm/zigler/Zigler.html . There was also a talk about it on zig showtime: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fIxNEILcNGM

Comment: awesome! If you post this as an answer I'll mark it correct so it's easy for people to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Zigler package can be used: https://github.com/ityonemo/zigler, https://hex.pm/packages/zigler

```
defmodule ExampleZig do
  use Zig
  ~Z"""
  /// nif: example_fun/2
  fn example_fun(value1: f64, value2: f64) bool {
    return value1 > value2;
  }
  """
end

test "example nifs" do
  assert ExampleZig.example_fun(0.8, -0.8)
  refute ExampleZig.example_fun(0.1, 0.4)
end
```